# Duplicate images removal via cli

Tags: ubuntu, image-processing, duplicates

In linux environment I would need to remove duplicate images by md5 of the file, but before deleting, I want to write in a file some CSV list of

Deleted File ->  Linked First File
Deleted File ->  Linked File

Etc.

The problem is that I have a  structure of

Main Folder
   Subfolder
       Sub-Sub Folder
            Sub-Sub-Sub Folder
                    Images

With more than 200.000 Files

So Script should be quite nice not to hang and to be fast.

Which direction would you suggest?

I have ubuntu under hand.

UPDATE:

I have found a script which does with small modification what I need. It search and find the md5 duplicates and removes  the duplicates. Only last step needed is to make a file with list of  removed file -> duplicate that stays

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/home/gevork/Desktop/webserver/maps.am/all_tiles/dubai_test"

find $DIR -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort > /home/gevork/Desktop/webserver/maps.am/all_tiles/dubai_test/sums-sorted.txt

OLDSUM=""
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat /home/gevork/Desktop/webserver/maps.am/all_tiles/dubai_test/sums-sorted.txt`; do
 NEWSUM=`echo "$i" | sed 's/ .*//'`
 NEWFILE=`echo "$i" | sed 's/^[^ ]* *//'`
 if [ "$OLDSUM" == "$NEWSUM" ]; then
  echo rm  "$NEWFILE"
 else
  OLDSUM="$NEWSUM"
  OLDFILE="$NEWFILE"
 fi
done
```

Comment: You have images in `Main Folder`, and also in `Subfolder` of `Main Folder`, and so on ? Also, do you want to decide whether a file is an image or do you know that all files in these folders are images ? Or you simply want to remove duplicate files, no matter what they are ?

Comment: @mmgp All files are in end subfolder in level 3. All are images of 256X256 size.  I need to delete duplicates by md5 and write a  text file where will be list of deleted file ->not deleted duplicate

Comment: Are they exact copies, i.e. not even exif data is modified ? I don't see the reason to this be tagged as image-processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find Python a nice tool for these tasks, and is more portable too (although you have restricted the question to Linux). The code below will keep the oldest file (by creation time) among the duplicates, if that doesn't matter to you then it can be simplified. To use it, save it as, for example, "remove_dups.py", and run as `python remove_dumps.py startdir`. From `startdir`, it will look for directories that 3 levels deep, and calculate the md5 sum of the contents there. It stores a list of file names per hash. The text file you are after is printed to stdout, so you actually want to run it as `python remove_dumps.py startdir > myoutputfile.txt`. It will also store the starting directory in this output file. Each other line is formatted as: `md5sum: file1, file2, file3, ...` for duplicate files. The first of these is kept, the others are removed.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import hashlib
from collections import defaultdict

BIG_ENOUGH_CTIME = 2**63-1

start_dir = sys.argv[1]

hash_file = defaultdict(list)
level3_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(start_dir, "*", "*", "*", "*"))
for name in level3_files:
    try:
        md5 = hashlib.md5(open(name).read()).hexdigest()
    except Exception, e:
        sys.stderr.write("Failed for %s. %s\n" % (name, e))
    else:
        # If you don't care about keeping the oldest between the duplicates,
        # the following files can be simplified.
        try:
            ctime = os.stat(name).st_ctime
        except Exception, e:
            sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % e)
            hash_file[md5].append((BIG_ENOUGH_CTIME, name))
        else:
            hash_file[md5].append((ctime, name))

print "base: %s" % (os.path.abspath(start_dir))
for md5, l in hash_file.items():
    if len(l) == 1:
        continue

    # Keep the oldest file between the duplicates.
    l = sorted(l)
    name = [data[1] for data in l]

    # md5sum: list of files. The first in the list is kept, the others are
    # removed.
    print "%s: %s" % (md5, ','.join('"%s"' % n for n in name))

    original = name.pop(0)
    for n in name:
        print "%s->%s" % (n, original)
        sys.stderr.write("Removing %s\n" % n)
        try:
            os.remove(n)
        except Exception, e:
            sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % e)
```

Comment: But After  deletion of files I would need some  txt file with list, where it says DELETED_FILE->ORIGINAL; DELETED2->ORIGINAL2;

Comment: This list is already produced, only in a different format. Do you want me to adjust the code for that specific format or are you saying that this can't be done with this code ?

Comment: if you would adjust, it would be a big favour for me :) Anyway I would like to thank you so much.

Comment: @MR.GEWA see the update, it is a minor adjust. If you want only this output, comment the other print statements.